# hadoop-aws compile dependencies on jackson library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to write a Spark program using Java to fetch records from oracle database and write it into S3 bucket. To access bucket using s3a:// convention, I have added hadoop-aws as dependency in the pom.xml.

I have added below dependencies in the pom.xml file :

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
    <spark.version>3.0.2</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.690</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to run the program but got dependency error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.ScalaTypeModifierModule.$init$(ScalaTypeModifier.scala:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
```

After bit of research, I got to know the hadoop-aws has compilation dependency on com.fasterxml.jackson.core as mentioned here :

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.8.5

So, I updated my pom.xml with the below dependencies :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But, I am still getting the same error. I am not sure what else I am missing here.

Comment: If you run `mvn dependency:list` what versions do you see for the different jackson dependencies? I'm guessing you are pulling in conflicting jackson dependencies through spark-core and hadoop-aws.

One way to get a consistent set of jackson dependencies is using [jackson-bom](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-bom). Try with a jackson version like 2.10.5 since spark-core:3.0.2 depends on 2.10.0

Comment: Best to switch to hadoop-3.3.2 artifacts *everywhere* and use the aws-sdk-bundle JAR which includes the version of jackson, httpclient etc which the AWS libraries need. Anything else is a losing battle